# Find the sum of sinusoidal harmonics with NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have the following formula for computing the Z^2 value. My t(time) and v(pulse frequency) are both NumPy arrays with the same length, whereas n(harmonics) is an integer value between 1 and 3, and N is the single integer value.

[image: Formula for Z^2 statistic]

Below, you see my naive attempt but couldn't figure out how to exactly include harmonics and all:

```
phase = t*v
zstat = (2/N)*np.sum(np.sum(np.cos(phase))**2 + np.sum(np.sin(phase))**2)
```

I need to iterate over all frequencies to find the highest Z, so I have attempted this:

```
for f in frequencies:
        phase = timenp * frequencies 
zstat += (np.sum(np.cos(k*phase[:N]))**2 + np.sum(np.sin(k*phase[:N]))**2)
zstat = zstat * 2/N
```

However, I am receiving this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
```

(28005,) (400,)

What is wrong with the code and how do I fix it?

Comment: Since v is a vector and t_j a scalar, shouldn't it be phi_j = v_j * t_j ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem:

- by using phase[:N] so it sum from first element to N-element.
- by using a for loop over k instead of your first np.sum().

So it looks like

```
for k in [1,2,3]: 
  zstat += (np.sum(np.cos(k*phase[:N]))**2 + np.sum(np.sin(k*phase[:N]))**2)
zstat = zstat * 2/N
```

Note that maybe it can be optimized, if you can avoid to calculate cos(phase[:N]) k-time it is better.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question. I need to iterate over frequencies but I receive the errors above. Is it possible to also iterate over frequencies?

Comment: @SaraKrauss can you provide a complete example, so others (and I) can test the code ? With a small set of data for example. Looks like your datas don't have the same shape for some reason.

edit: your error is probably because you do phase = timenp * frequencies instead of phase = timenp * f

Comment: @SaraKrauss Also zstat is not in the for loop. So...it's a bit confusing !